# Sharing MySQL address book with Outlook?

Tags: mysql, outlook

I am looking to take a central address book in MySQL and share it with users on the network who use Outlook. What do I need to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Outlook would support an ODBC-type connection native to mysql for its address book. I do know that it *does* support LDAP, though, so you could write a simple script to periodically sync your mysql data over to an openldap server and then point your outlook clients there.

Comment: Would setting up an OpenLDAP server with Back-SQL eliminate the need for the script that synchronizes?

Comment: OpenLDAP + Back-SQL would indeed eliminate the need to synchronize.  I gather it can be slower than the native back-hdb mode, and of course it will load the SQL DB when users access it whereas a native LDAP mirror will be independent, so be aware of those aspects if performance is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I am not aware of any canned solutions that would allow this.  I believe what you will need is a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's actually any good, but i found this: http://www.geniusconnect.com/articles/GeniusConnect/2/3/2/ which claims to do what you want